# I'm making a multiplayer game and I need to verify that players aren't speed hacking

Tags: network-programming

For security reasons I have a feeling that that testing should be done server side. Nonetheless, that would be rather taxing on the server, right? Given the gear and buffs a player is wearing they will have a higher movement speed, so each time they move I would need to calculate that new constant and see if their movement is legitimate (using TCP so don't need to worry about lost, unordered packets). I realize I could instead just save the last movement speed and only recalculate it if they've changed something affecting their speed, but even then that's another check.

Another idea I had is that the server randomly picks data that the client is sending it and verifies it and gives each client a trust rating. A low enough trust rating would mean every message from the client would be inspected and all of their actions would be logged in a more verbose manner. I would then know they're hacking by inspecting the logs and could ban/suspend them as well as undo any benefits they may have spread around through hacking.

Any advice is appreciated, thank you.

Edit: I just realized there's also the case where a hacker could send tiny movements (within the capability of their regular speed) in a very high succession. Each individual movement alone would be legite, but the cumulative effect would be speed hacking. What are some ways around this?

Comment: Specifically, what's the language you are developing this in?

Comment: @George: Server is C++, client is C#.

Answer (score 6):

The standard way to deal with this problem is to have the server calculate all movement. The only thing that the clients should send to the server are commands, e.g. "move left" and the server should then calculate how fast the player moves etc., then finally send the updated position back to the client.

If you leave any calculation at all on the client, the chances are that sooner or later someone will find a way to cheat.

Comment: +1 for doing the movement itself on the server. What you want to do is let the server handle movement, and have the client guess where they're going to end up/resynchronize when the server tells them where they are. That way, if someone hacks up the client, it doesn't actually help them at all because they'll keep rubberbanding back to where they should be.

Comment: actually, in pretty much every professional client-server video game, the client has authority of their character's position because popping and sliding are not acceptable.  (which yes, is then validated by a server simulation, with some tolerance, which yes exposes the game to hacks, which are then addressed by detection and banning)

Comment: That seems really taxing... could you imagine if WoW did that for its millions of players? Does it do that? I imagine there has to be some type of shortcut like Jeff said.

Comment: @Jeff - I glossed over this a bit :-) agree that such games let the client position diverge from the server position in order to give the feel of responsiveness and correct screen behaviour. But that's just for client display reasons - the "official" position for the calculation of game logic (missile hits, triggers etc.) is still generally done on the server....

Comment: As far as I know, WoW does exactly what Jeff states. Client sends positions as requests; server accepts them or rejects them based on internal feasibility checks. This is pretty much what I put in my answer.

Comment: also, your assumptions about performance concerns are perhaps premature. computers are extremely fast. most actual issues stem from either poor algorithmic decisions or operating at an inappropriate abstraction level.  "for(int i = 0; i < numObjects; ++i) objects[i].pos += objects[i].vel * dt;" is super fast, until you: put objects an stl array (or something worse), put pos and vel in very different places in memory, etc.  There are even smarter things you can do but i expect if you just do the simplest thing, you might be surprised how efficient it is. ask another q if you need more info.

Comment: Ok, thanks for the great replies. The one last issue I have with this is this: What if the cheater spams "move left" commands? How would I know that it wasn't due to lag that all those commands piled up in my queue?

Comment: "move left" in this context really means "start moving left". So extra sends are redundant and don't allow any sort of cheating.

Comment: @Kylotan: How would you implement something like that?

Comment: @Kylotan: I feel like I would need some type of timer running on how often it is possible to process data on a socket... seems very intense.

Comment: Implement something like what? Sockets are irrelevant here. This is about player characters. Sockets are just the physical layer for getting the information to the characters.

Comment: Sorry, let me clarify. When I receive a "move left" from the client I would take their movement constant and use that to decide how much they should move left. I would do that instantly basically and already may have received another move left. I can process them as fast as they can come. How would I implement the "start moving left" idea without some type of timer?

Comment: Sorry for not responding sooner: I've not been on this site recently. The idea of a 'movement constant' is an odd one. Most continuous motion in games is done by setting a velocity and regularly updating position based on that. You do the regular updates server side. All the client does is tell you when it wants to change speed or direction.

Answer (score 3):

> [...] testing should be done server side. Nonetheless, that would be rather taxing on the server, right?

Nope. This is the way to do it. It's the only way to do it. All talk of checking trust or whatever is inherently flawed, one way or another.

If you're letting the player send positions:

- Check where someone claims they are.
- Compare that to where they were a short while ago. Allow a tiny bit of deviation to account for network lag.
- If they're moving too quickly, reposition them somewhere more reasonable. Small errors may be due to long periods of lag, so clients should use interpolation to smooth out these corrections.
- If they're moving far too quickly, disconnect them. And check for bugs in your code.
- Don't forget to handle legitimate traversals over long distance, eg. teleports.

Answer (score 2):

The way around this is that all action is done on the server.  Never trust any information that comes from the client.  If anybody actually plays your game, somebody will reverse-engineer the communication to the server and figure out how to take advantage of it.

You can't assign a random trust rating, because cautious cheaters will cheat only when they really need to.  That gives them a considerable advantage with a low chance of being spotted cheating.

And, yes, this means you can't get by with a low-grade server, but there's really no other method of preventing client-side cheating.

Comment: One method I was thinking of to make it more difficult would be to have matching encryption/decryption algorithms in the client and the server. The encryption/decryption would be done using a server-generated key which would be transferred during the "handshake" between the client and the server.  Each would then use that key with the enc./dec. algorithms to send their data thus making it pretty difficult to crack a session unique key. The key could be refreshed every ten minutes to further frustrate cracking efforts. This would fail when they reverse engineer the client, unfortunately.

Comment: @returneax:  ALL such schemes fail when the cheaters reverse engineer the client, unfortunately.  If your game is popular, this means that somebody will do that, and the rest of your players will be playing with cheaters in their midst, which really isn't much fun, and will usually lead to your game becoming unpopular.

Answer (score 1):

If you are developing in a language that has access to Windows API function calls, I have found from my own studies in speed hacking, that you can easily identify a speed hacker by calling two functions and comparing results.

[TimeGetTime](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd757629%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

and...

[GetTickCount](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms724408%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

Both functions will return the number of seconds since the system started.  However, TimeGetTime is much more accurate than GetTickCount, whereas `TimeGetTime` is accurate up to ~1ms vs. `GetTickCount`, which is accurate at around ~50ms

Even though there is a small lag between these two functions, if you turn on a speed hacking application (pick your poison), you *should* see a very large difference between the two result sets, sometimes even up to a couple of seconds.  The difference is very noticable.

Write a simple application that returns the `GetTickCount` and `TimeGetTime` results, without the speed hacking application running, and leave it running.  Compare the results and display the difference -- you should see a very small difference between the two.  Then, with your application still running, turn on the speed hacking application and you will see the very large difference in the two result sets.

The trick is figuring out what threshold will constitue suspicious activity.

Comment: Interesting idea, but lag would be a major issue here, right?

Comment: Lag is an issue here, and also people hacking the client app.  A simple application that calls `TimeGetTime` and sends the result over the net connection will be easy to reverse engineer and hack.